# Rails 5: save JSON attributes to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm currently following an API tutorial with HTTParty. Everything is working and I'm happy that I've learned something new. Like always the tutorial leaves me open with some questions.

For now I can call the meetup API with a `GET` request and fetch all events from a meetup. The `JSON` is parsed to my view, but now I would like to display each event individually for example:

```
<%= @events.each do |event| %>
 <%= event.name %>
 <%= event.date %>
 <%= event.organizator %>
<% end %>
```

This is my Model:

```
class Meetup
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.meetup.com'

  attr_reader :options

  def initialize
    api_key = ''
    @options = {
      query: {
        key: api_key,
        sign: "true",
        desc: "true",
        page: 3
      }
    }
  end

  def get_data
    self.class.get('/operation-code-hampton-roads/events', @options)
  end

  def events
    if get_data.code.to_i == 200
      get_data.parsed_response
    else
      raise "Error fetching data from Meetup API"
    end
  end
end
```

My Controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
  @services = Service.all

respond_to do |format|
  @events = Meetup.new.events
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @events }
  end
end

end
```

My view:

```
<%= @events.each do |event| %>
 <!-- event.name ? -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong title. I would like to save the JSON objects in my database and then map them accordingly. Afterwards I would like to display them in my view

Comment: can you update you're question with sample response?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's my first time working with JSON, I thought it would be more difficult to display the `@events` in my view.

But it's quite simple and I don't even need to create a new migration!

I simply added this to my view and everything is working!

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<%= event["name"] %>
<%= event["status"] %>
<%= event["local_date"] %>
<%= event["local_time"] %>
<%= event["yes_rsvp_count"] %>
<%= event["venue"]["city"] %>
<%= event["venue"]["address_1"] %>
<%= raw (event["description"]).truncate(100) %>
<% end %>
```